# My _prepareCollection() is failing

Tags: magento-1.6, reports

I have the following code that does not produce anything on screen adn I cannot work out what is wrong with it.

```
protected function _prepareCollection(){
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('neq' => 'complete'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('neq' => 'canceled'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('neq' => 'closed'));

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfsg'=>$resource->getTableName('nct_sales_flat_shipment_grid')),'sfsg.order_increment_id=main_table.increment_id',array('shiped' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sfsg.created_at SEPARATOR " | ")'), ));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();        
}
```

And in _prepareColumns() I have...

```
  protected function _prepareColumns(){        
    $this->addColumn('shiped', array(
           'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date Shipped'),
           'index'     => 'shiped',
          'type'      => 'datetime',
          'filter_index'=>'sfsg.created_at',
    ));
  }
```

Why is this not working. I am using Magento ver. 1.6.2.0.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any errors? "Is not working" doesn't mean much.

Comment: No errors nothing. the page produces the title of the report but nothing comes out apart from the Magento footer.

Comment: Check the `var/log` folder for a file with the same name as your report bug number. It contains the error message

Comment: Thank you. 
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getTableName() on a non-object in

Comment: Removing getTableName() produces a report! Not waht I'm after but I am getting somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: `$resource` is not defined. that's why you get the error

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by marius you have a problem with `$resource` being undefined. If you add the following to your code:

```
$collection->getTableName
```

instead of

```
$resource->getTableName
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To add shipment created at date to the sales collection.

```
        $collections->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfsg' => $collections->getTable('sales/shipment')), 
                                     'main_table.increment_id = sfsg.increment_id',
                                     array('shipment_created_at'=>'sfsg.created_at'));
```